# How to set data to CKEDITOR after CKEDITOR load?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <textarea name="template_body">
    </textarea>
</div>

<script>
    CKEDITOR.replace('template_body');
</script>
```

And JS-code:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.instances["template_body"];
var requestGetValue = $http({
    method: "get",
    url: "/getValue",
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    mimeType: 'application/json'
});
requestGetValue.success(function (data) {
        editor.setData(data);
});
```

But sometimes my `data` was loaded to CKEDITOR, and sometimes wasn't loaded. How to set data to CKEDITOR after load CKEDITOR?

Comment: try using async:false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the problem is with the ajax response delay.

Try the following,

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'template_body' );

editor.on( 'contentDom', function(){
 var requestGetValue = $http({
    method: "get",
    url: "/getValue",
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    mimeType: 'application/json'
});
requestGetValue.success(function (data) {
        editor.setData(data);
});

});
```

Comment: If I use **.on()**, the request **requestGetValue** send every time

Comment: Then, use setTimeout to find whether editor instance is ready.If it is ready, then call setData and clear out the time interval.